# Visual Studio Code Vim: How do I bind shift-space

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm trying to use Vim mode in Visual Studio Code, using their VSCodeVim extension

In my old `vimrc` it looks like:

```
map <S-space> <Esc>
```

In Code's `settings.json` I've tried:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": ["<S-Space>"],
        "after": ["<Esc>"]
    }
],
```

Doesn't work :(

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a bug in their addon, not something I was doing wrong.

[Here's a workaround](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/2584#issuecomment-385561286)

Inside just the normal `keybindings.json`:

```
{
    "key": "shift+space",
    "command": "extension.vim_escape",
    "when": "editorTextFocus"
 },
```